# Duplicate files in Android Studio project view

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I have a strange issue where project specific root level files (.gitignore, gradlew, gradle.properties, etc) show up twice in Android Studio's project view. Does anybody know how to fix this?

I've tried re-importing the project (after deleting the .iml and .idea file/folder).

[image]

Comment: Are you using Linux links by any means? Seems like I get this when trying to point a project to a location which is under a link.

Comment: @Renato haven't had it resolved. I believe I was told it's a feature/expected behavior. I'm on OS X.

Comment: I only got duplicate files on my projects which were on a separate disk partition (hence the use of a link)... on my "normal" projects, I don't have this problem , and I certainly consider this to be a bug, not a feature :)

Answer (score 22):

I found exactly the same problem recently when I created a new Gradle project and imported into IntelliJ.  However, the root cause seems to be the use of symbolic links when importing the project.

I have the following symbolic link:

```
/data -> /Users/<user>/data
```

When I originally imported my project, I imported `/data/checkouts/<project_dir>` but found that I had duplicate files from the top level directory exactly like as shown above.

However, I removed the project and attempted to import it again, this time using the full path of `/Users/<user>/data/checkouts/<project_dir>` and found that I no longer see the duplicates.

I haven't seen this problem before when importing an eclipse or Maven project, so can only imagine that it might be related to the use of the Gradle plugin for IntelliJ.

Comment: WHOA! Finally! For SBT too! Thank you!

Comment: This was haunting me for quite a while. Solved based on your answer, thanks!

Comment: Just to make clear you can fix this by avoiding any symbolic links in the path when opening a project seems to do the trick

Comment: And how can you solve this once the project has already been imported?

Comment: Hey @Fran, I think the answer already covers what to do. I'm not sure if there is a way to change the path to a module that is better/faster than simply removing it and re-importing it using the absolute path.

Comment: Holy hell. I struggled with this all day. This was not just aesthetic, but was breaking my gradle build completely in all sorts of bizarre ways.  You saved my day (well my next day :D)