# IDEA showing a project twice in tree

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, kotlin

I have a Kotlin project with Gradle that has two children. Whenever I try to open it in IDEA, one of the children is shown twice in the tree.

[image: Screenshot]

In the tree, you can see two projects at top level, grpc and grp. The issue is that grpc (from top level) is the same project as the grpc that's a children of grp.

Here are my Gradle build files:

The parent gradle.build:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.1'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

The gradle.settings file:

```
include ':grpstd', ':grpc'
```

The grpc gradle.build:

```
apply plugin: 'antlr'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

mainClassName = 'sron.grpc.MainKt'

compileKotlin.dependsOn generateGrammarSource

generateGrammarSource {
    arguments += ['-package', 'sron.grpc.compiler.internal']
}

dependencies {
    antlr 'org.antlr:antlr4:4.5.2-1'

    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'commons-cli:commons-cli:1.3.1'
    compile 'org.ow2.asm:asm:5.0.4'
    compile project(':grpstd')

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:$kotlin_version"
}
```

The grpstd gradle.build:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:$kotlin_version"
}
```

**Why is that project being shown twice? How can I prevent it?**

Comment: I have the same problem with a Groovy project. I believe it's due to Auto-import, but don't know any resolution yet.

Comment: Try deleting the .gradle folder, close the project and reimport the project from gradle.

Comment: This sort of thing can happen when the project directory is accessed via a symbolic link. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25888978/14379

Answer (score 1):

Open your `project structure` dialog (you can use `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S`), turn to the `Modules` section, check if you have duplicated module defined there.
If there is, remove the unnecessary ones.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try disabling the *Create separate module per source set* option when importing the Gradle module.

[image: import wizard]

So, the full steps are:

1. Open Modules [image]
2. Remove the gradle module
3. Re-import the module. On the second page of the import wizard **make sure you disable the option: *Create separate module per source set***

Comment: That isn't related. "Module" refers to IntelliJ's own module structure (see Project Settings), not Gradle's.

Comment: Actually the option that fixed this for me was right above the option you were highlighting: "use explicit module groups"